# Swift 4 - Custom UICollectionReusableView with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipickerview

I have built a custom `UICollectionReusableView` class like so:

```
protocol ReviewFooterDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func submitReviewDelegate(text: String, rating: Float)
}

class ReviewFooterCell: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet var text: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var submitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var rating: CosmosView!
    @IBOutlet var problem: UITextField!
    var reviewFooterDelegate: ReviewFooterDelegate!

    @IBAction func submitButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        reviewFooterDelegate.submitReviewDelegate(text: self.text.text, rating: Float(rating.rating))
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UITextField` to show a `UIPickerView`, this is what I have in my controller that is using this custom class:

In my `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method:

```
    let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "ReviewsFooter", for: indexPath) as! ReviewFooterCell
    footerView.reviewFooterDelegate = self
    let problemGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(problemTapped))
    footerView.problem.addGestureRecognizer(problemGesture)
    return footerView
```

And here is the problemTapped method:

```
@objc func problemTapped(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfessionalReviews.donePicker))
        doneButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 30.0 / 255.0, green: 53.0 / 255.0, blue: 94.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfessionalReviews.cancelPicker))
        cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 30.0 / 255.0, green: 53.0 / 255.0, blue: 94.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        /*
        problem.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        view.addSubview(problem)
        problem.inputView = pickerView
        problem.becomeFirstResponder()
        */
    }
```

And now I am stuck on what to do next, how would I set the `UITextField` in my custom class as the first responder?

Do I want to set the gesture in my class instead of my controller? (if so how?) and then use another delegate method to be called when my donePicker or cancelPicker methods are called to get the return value in the controller?

Comment: Why you wanna add gesture on textfield, you can access textfield delegates and if you wanna show picker use inputAccessoryView as you commented

Comment: also you could add a button before the utextfield with no text and add problem tapped as target to show the picker

Comment: one way is to have a done button in a view that contains the picker and that button, clicking it hides the view , after user selects his row

Comment: Also, please review the how-to-ask guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, you do not need a UITapGestureRecognizer in order to accomplish what you are asking:

> UITextField to show a UIPickerView.

Instead set the textField's `inputView` to your pickerView. Here is a code sample that does this. The view controller has a single textField that brings up a pickerView when tapped. This project is on github; see references below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField: UITextField!

    var pickOption = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

    var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()

        // Assign the pickerView delegate
        pickerView.delegate = self

        // Assign the textField's inputView to be the picker
        pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView
    }

    // UIPickerViewDelegate methods
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickOption.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickOption[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        pickerTextField.text = pickOption[row]
    }
}
```

Since your textView is contained within a UICollectionReusableView, you can have a function in your cell's class to set the textView's inputView like this:

```
class ReviewFooterCell: UICollectionReusableView {
    func setTextFieldInputView(pickerView: UIPickerView) {
        problem.inputView = pickerView   
    }    
}
```

The result is similar to this gif:

[image]

**References**

- [Github: UIPickerView-Tutorial](https://github.com/starkindustries/UIPickerView-Tutorial/blob/master/Blog%20Project/picker%20textfield%20demo/ViewController.swift)
- [Apoorv Mote: UIPickerview as inputview to uitextfield in swift](http://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/)

Comment: But I would need this in a custom class as its a class cell of UICollectionReusableView

Comment: The textView inside a custom class is still set the same way. For a custom class you can have a function that sets the textView's inputView. I updated my answer.